# How to use ngModel's instance of FormControl in the ngOnInit() method?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I was thinking of using Angular Material autocomplete module like they have an example [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/vnmqnvqelqd?file=app%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.ts).
They say in the overview that template-driven forms are possible to use. So I thought I'd give it a go.

Template:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="doSmth()" #f="ngForm">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input type="text" required id="name" (ngModel)="myControl" name="name" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto">
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">{{ option }}</mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!f.form.valid">Click</button>
</form>
```

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'autocomplete-filter-example',
  templateUrl: 'autocomplete-filter-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['autocomplete-filter-example.css'],
})
export class AutocompleteFilterExample implements OnInit {
  myControl: FormControl();
  options: string[] = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map((value: string) => this.filter(value))
      );
  }

  private filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.options.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
}
```

Trouble is that when I run it, I get an error:

```
AppComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'valueChanges' of undefined
```

So I'm guessing the ngModel was binded after the init? Or why doesn't this work? Do I need to use a sepaparte instance of `FormControl`?

Comment: you has a FormControl, so use `<input [formControl]="myControl">` not (ngModel). But you need declare as `myControl:FormControl=new FormControl()` -or equal to **new** FormControl() in ngOnInit- Therefore you needn't enclosed in a `<form>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `ngModel` and template driven form instead of form control you can use it together with `ngModelChange`. If you then want to work with observables or plain string array, is up to you. Here is using plain string array:

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input type="text" [ngModel]="myControl" name="name" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" (ngModelChange)="doFilter($event)" required>
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions" [value]="option">
      {{ option }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Initially we could give the `filteredOptions` the value of `options`. Let's use spread operator to not create reference between the two arrays:

```ts
options: string[] = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
filteredOptions = [... this.options];
myControl = '';
```

Then the `doFilter()` function would look like this:

```ts
doFilter(value) {
  const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
  this.filteredOptions = this.options.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
}
```

**DEMO: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pzjvde-iznerz?file=app/autocomplete-simple-example.ts)**

If you don't need the template driven form, you can simply do this without the form tags.

If you are for the future planning to make http-requests to get the data for the autocomplete, as mentioned, you can also work with observables. If using observables at this point already can be more wise, since it would easily be replaced. If so, this is the option with using observables instead of string array:

```ts
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

// ...

filteredOptions = of(this.options);

doFilter(value) {
  const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
  this.filteredOptions = of(this.options.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)));
}
```

and use the async pipe in view:

```html
<mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
```

**DEMO: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pzjvde-l5pt5l?file=app%2Fautocomplete-simple-example.html)**

Answer (score 0):

FormControl is used in Reactive forms. You may try below code.

```
myControl: any;
@ViewChild('f') ngForm: NgForm;

ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = this.ngForm.form.valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
    console.log(x);
  })
}
```

don't forget to unsubscribe. Also you may need to use [(ngModel)] instead of (ngModel).